# add multi text field using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i want to create a form to insert  course ID and credit and when the user click add two text field will appear together , i tried to add two input boxes but when i clicked add only one appear

thanks in advance ..

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
 var maxField = 10; //Input fields increment limitation
 var addButton = $('.add_button'); //Add button selector
 var wrapper = $('.field_wrapper'); //Input field wrapper
 var fieldHTML = '<div><input type="text" name="field_name[]" value=""/><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="remove_button" title="Remove field"><img src="remove-icon.png"/></a></div>'; //New input field html 
 var x = 1; //Initial field counter is 1
 $(addButton).click(function(){ //Once add button is clicked
  if(x < maxField){ //Check maximum number of input fields
   x++; //Increment field counter
   $(wrapper).append(fieldHTML); // Add field html
  }
 });
 $(wrapper).on('click', '.remove_button', function(e){ //Once remove button is clicked
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).parent('div').remove(); //Remove field html
  x--; //Decrement field counter
 });
});
</script>
```

```css
<style type="text/css">
input[type="text"]{height:20px; vertical-align:top;}
.field_wrapper div{ margin-bottom:10px;}
.add_button{ margin-top:10px; margin-left:10px;vertical-align: text-bottom;}
.remove_button{ margin-top:10px; margin-left:10px;vertical-align: text-bottom;}
</style>
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<form name="codexworld_frm" action="" method="post">
<div class="field_wrapper">
 <div>
     <input type="text" name="field_name[]" value=""/>
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="add_button" title="Add field"><img src="add-icon.png"/></a>
    </div>
</div>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="SUBMIT"/>
</form>
</body>
```

Comment: `fieldHTML` does not have `2` elements

Comment: you only have one input within your template... just add another

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the field to the template...

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
 var maxField = 10; //Input fields increment limitation
 var addButton = $('.add_button'); //Add button selector
 var wrapper = $('.field_wrapper'); //Input field wrapper
 var fieldHTML = '<div><input type="text" name="field_name[]" value=""/> <input type="text" name="credit" value=""/><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="remove_button" title="Remove field"><img src="remove-icon.png"/></a></div>'; //New input field html 
 var x = 1; //Initial field counter is 1
 $(addButton).click(function(){ //Once add button is clicked
  if(x < maxField){ //Check maximum number of input fields
   x++; //Increment field counter
   $(wrapper).append(fieldHTML); // Add field html
  }
 });
 $(wrapper).on('click', '.remove_button', function(e){ //Once remove button is clicked
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).parent('div').remove(); //Remove field html
  x--; //Decrement field counter
 });
});
</script>
```

```css
<style type="text/css">
input[type="text"]{height:20px; vertical-align:top;}
.field_wrapper div{ margin-bottom:10px;}
.add_button{ margin-top:10px; margin-left:10px;vertical-align: text-bottom;}
.remove_button{ margin-top:10px; margin-left:10px;vertical-align: text-bottom;}
</style>
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<form name="codexworld_frm" action="" method="post">
<div class="field_wrapper">
 <div>
     <input type="text" name="field_name[]" value=""/>
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="add_button" title="Add field"><img src="add-icon.png"/></a>
    </div>
</div>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="SUBMIT"/>
</form>
</body>
```